# Google Chart API (deprecated) show vertical y axis label

Tags: google-visualization

I know the Google chart API I am using is deprecated, but it cannot be replaced with the latest API. I would like to change the y axis label to print vertically. How can I do this?

Here is the Google Chart API URL:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chtt=Visual+acuity+change+from+BVD+to+6+months&chco=00aa00,0000aa,aaaa00,aa6600,aa0000,000000&chxt=x,y,x,y&chxr=0,0,6,1|1,-50,50,5&chxl=2:|Time%20(months)|3:|LogMAR%20Letters&chg=0,50,1,0&chm=o,00aa00,0,-1,4.0|o,0000aa,1,-1,4.0|o,aaaa00,2,-1,4.0|o,aa6600,3,-1,4.0|o,000000,4,-1,4.0|d,000000,5,-1,8.0&chma=|5,100&chs=800x340&cht=lxy&chd=e:AAKPVHgAqP1H..,gApmq4szszszsz,AAKPVHgAqP1H..,gAlHmZnCnCnCoU,AAKPVHgAqP1H..,gAhxi2jSi4i2jN,AAKPVHgAqP1H..,gAfXgAgAfXeufX,AAKPVHgAqP1H..,gAa4bha4ZmZmZm,AAKPVHgAqP1H..,gAh6mLjMjMjMjm&chdl=FRB!%20Users%20Top%2010%25|FRB!%20Users%20Top%2025%25|FRB!%20Users%20Average|FRB!%20Users%20Bottom%2025%25|FRB!%20Users%20Bottom%2010%25|Doctor%20Doctor's%20Patients&chls=2|2|2,6,3|2|2|5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    use this link 
    http://psychopyko.com/tutorial/how-to-use-google-charts/
    http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?
cht=bhg&chs=550x230&chd=t:100,50,115,80&
chxt=x,y&chxl=1:|Python|Java|Ruby|.NET&
chxr=0,0,120&chds=0,120&
chco=4D89F9&
chbh=35,0,15&
chg=8.33,0,5,5
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not resolve my issue. I need the graph to be in the normal orientation as it is now, but would prefer it if the y axis label could be printed vertically instead of horizontally.